# Animated mathematics formulae in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation, math

so basically I want to show  mathematical formulae etc. dynamically as an explanation tool on a little static website. 
For example: have a matrix and a slider and animate the content of that matrix to contain the slider value plus the resulting determinant. (Basically I want to do stuff like 3b1b, but in a browser;) 
I have already tinkered with the idea and tried to do first tests with MathJax, but its dynamic rendering capabilities are (as of my experience) severely limited.
Also I've failed to find a library specifically designed for this (most Maths libraries are focused on showing graphs and stuff, not maths text).
If anyone has an idea on how to (easily, I'm not a huge JS expert, sadly) implement this, I would be happy to hear it ;)

Comment: I suspect you're going to have to do a fair bit of the heavy lifting yourself if you want to really control how it looks. I know the library `d3` is very popular for visualisations and has many 3rd party additions to it that might help you.

Comment: This sounds like that Big Bang Theory episode ... *I have this great idea, I just need a computer nerd to do all the work* - [Jimmy Speckerman](https://icanhazcode.com/speckerman.html)